# Adjusting screen brightness using WindowManager stops working after inactivity

Tags: android

I'm using this code to change an Activity's brightness by dimming it.

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParameters = getWindow().getAttributes();
layoutParameters.screenBrightness = 0.0075f;
getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParameters);
```

I'm also adjusting the android.provider.Settings.System brightness.

My problem is, that after ~8 seconds of inactivity, the screen brightness resorts back to normal (i.e. brightens again). Does anyone know why this is happening and how I could change that setting as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it would override your layoutParameters, but perhaps try using a full [wakeLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html) to keep the screen from dimming.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the value of Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE from Automatic to manual, and then change the int value Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS. Only add these lines of code:

```
Settings.System.putInt(getActivity().getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE, Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_MANUAL);
Settings.System.putInt(getActivity().getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, brightness);//for persistent change
```